# Winterbash hats are misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

I've placed the "glare-reducers" hat on my avatar.
Whilst it lines up in the preview, on the main profile page it's shifted a few px right and down.

Odd.

[image]

Comment: x-site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373029/hat-gets-misplaced-both-in-icon-and-on-profile-picture-2021-winter-bash

Comment: This should be fixed - Could you check it out and confirm?

Comment: @Catija - Yes, indeed it is, thank you!